# Adding specific uv map to UVMap node in python script

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I am trying to create a script that at one part of it select a specific UV from the active object

(e.g. Cube object ⇒ 'UVMap_final')

I have managed to create the new node using:

uv_map_node = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')

But I cannot understand how to select and assign a UV to this node.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enabled Developer Extras in the preferences, you can see the attribute name linked to the field while hovering over it : `uv_map`

[image]

The field is a `StringProperty`, meaning you have to set it to a `str` value. It doesn't matter if it doesn't exist yet on the object data. If it doesn't it will be filled with red.

See :

```
import bpy

uv_map_node = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
uv_map_node.uv_map = "test"

uv_map_node2 = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap')
uv_map_node2.uv_map = "UVMap"
```

[image]

Comment: That works! I think what confuses me is that ..
uv_map_node = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeUVMap') ,  when adding .uv_map  i cant test as i get an error on the python console

Comment: What error do you get?  Would recommend using python console in conjunction with developer extras as suggested above.

Comment: @batFINGER can't reproduce it now, i get very confused where to look, either context or data etc.